# xslt - adding Lp. to node

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm new in xslt, so I've some problems with adding Lp to my transformation.

This's my simple xml data:

```
 <booking>
    <bookingID>ww1</bookingID>
    <voucherNumber>R-108</voucherNumber>
  </booking>
  <booking>
    <bookingID>ww2</bookingID>
    <voucherNumber>R-108</voucherNumber>
  </booking>
  <booking>
    <bookingID>ww3</bookingID>
    <voucherNumber>R-108</voucherNumber>
  </booking>
  <booking>
    <bookingID>ww4</bookingID>
    <voucherNumber>R-109</voucherNumber>
  </booking>
  <booking>
    <bookingID>ww5</bookingID>
    <voucherNumber>R-109</voucherNumber>
  </booking>
  <booking>
    <bookingID>ww6</bookingID>
    <voucherNumber>R-110</voucherNumber>
  </booking>
```

The key is voucherNumber, i need to add Lp for the same voucherNumber
I'need output text file to look like this:

```
ID;VN,LP
ww1;108;1
ww2;108;2
ww3;108;3
ww4;109;1
ww5;109;2
ww6;110;1
```

I add the key on voucherNumber

```
<xsl:key name="x" match="booking" use="voucherNumber"/>
```

in for-each statement I've add this code: it's adding me on the last position (i know that i can change this for another position) the number of count my items for the same voucherNumber, but how  i can add number Lp for the other items?

```
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="generate-id(.) =generate-id(key('x',voucherNumber)[last()])">
<xsl:value-of select="count(key('x',voucherNumber)) "/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
-- need LP for other items --
 </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I can use only version 1.0 of xslt stylesheet.
Thank you for your advice
Best regards

Comment: Can you show a bit more of your XSLT please? In particular, can you show the `for-each` statement that you mention? Thanks!

Comment: my for-each statements look like this: <xsl:for-each select="booking">

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what "Lp" means. Assuming you want to number the bookings sequentially, restarting on `voucherNumber`, try something like:

***-- Edit --***
*The proper solution here would be to use `<xsl:number>` to number the nodes. However, since I could not find a single combination of attributes that would work the same way with all XSLT 1.0 processors, I have resorted to the following hack:*

```
<xsl:key name="booking-by-voucherNumber" match="booking" use="voucherNumber"/>

<xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="booking">
        <!-- get id and voucher number -->  
        <xsl:variable name="id" select="generate-id()" />
        <xsl:for-each select="key('booking-by-voucherNumber', voucherNumber)">
            <xsl:if test="generate-id()=$id">
                <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <!-- new line -->   
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The LP it's mean singular. That's good resolution and it works for me! Thanks a lot! Regards

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to use Muenchian Grouping here, but what you probably should do is start off by selected the `booking` elements with the first occurrence of each distinct `voucherNumber`

```
<xsl:for-each select="booking[generate-id() = generate-id(key('x',voucherNumber)[1])]">
```

Then, you have a nested `xsl:for-each` where you get all the `booking` elements within that group (i.e. the `booking` elements with the same `voucherNumber`)

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('x', voucherNumber)">
```

Then, within this next `xsl:for-each` you can use the `position()` function to get the count of the record within that specific group

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" />

    <xsl:key name="x" match="booking" use="voucherNumber"/>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
      <xsl:for-each select="booking[generate-id() =generate-id(key('x',voucherNumber)[1])]">
          <xsl:for-each select="key('x', voucherNumber)">
              <xsl:value-of select="bookingID" />
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(voucherNumber, '-')" />
              <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
              <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note, this assumed your actual XML is well-formed and there is a single root element containing all your `booking` elements.